# wordpress plugin accessing post info

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am a novice to wordpress plugin development. I am trying to access the post information and based on if it is having a featured image I am creating a slide show. But the image url and post title are going out of my div tag. Below is my code.

```
    //function to display post info 
    function postsinfo_collage_display($attr, $content) {

    $plugins_url = plugins_url();

     $html = '<div id="pscanvas" class="row">
                    <div  class="row__inner mThumbnailScroller">';

    // The Query
    query_posts( array ('orderby' => 'date' ) );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $html .= '<div class="tile">
                            <div class="tile__media">';
        $html .='<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'">';
        $html .='<img class="tile__img"';
        $html .="src='".esc_url(the_post_thumbnail_url()). "'/>";
        $html .='</a></div><div class="tile__details">
              <div class="tile__title">';
        $html .= the_title();
        $html .='</div></div></div>';        
    } 
    endwhile;
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    $html .= '</div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                    window.jQuery || document.write(\'<script src="minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>\')
            (function($){
                $(window).load(function(){              
                });
            })(jQuery);</script>';

        return $html;

    }
```

The output I am getting is:

```
    <div class="entry-content">
            http://localhost:9085/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/call-of-duty-ghosts-20517-1366x768-1200x675.jpgpscanvashttp://localhost:9085/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Call-Of-Duty-Ghost-Background-For-Wallpaper-652-1200x675.jpgkwofkwc
        <div id="pscanvas" class="row">
         <div class="row__inner mThumbnailScroller ">
             <div id="mTS_1" class="mTSWrapper mTS_horizontal">
                 <div class="mTSAutoContainer mTSContainer" ">
                     <div class="tile">
                     <div class="tile__media">
                     <a href="http://localhost:9085/wordpress/2016/09/04/pscanvas/">
                     <img class="tile__img" src=""></a>
                     </div><div class="tile__details">
                     <div class="tile__title"></div></div></div>
                     <div class="tile"><div class="tile__media">
                     <a href="http://localhost:9085/wordpress/2016/05/03/kwofkwc/">
                     <img class="tile__img" src=""></a></div><div class="tile__details">
                     <div class="tile__title"></div></div></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
            <script>
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="minified/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')
            (function($){
                $(window).load(function(){              
                });
            })(jQuery);</script>
    <strong>Album Rating:</strong> <div class="genericon genericon-star"></div><br> </div>
```

I can see the image url should be inside the img tag but its coming out of the entire div tag.

Comment: Use : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: I tried that as well in the beginning. But the same output. I am not understanding why would the url come out of my main pscanvas div tag. The same is working fine if i use echo get_permalink().

Comment: Thanks. Changed to this : $imgurl=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
    $posturl= get_permalink();
    $title=the_title();
 $html .= '<div class="tile"><div class="tile__media">';
 $html .='<a href="'. $posturl .'">';
 $html .='<img class="tile__img" src="'. $imgurl.'"/>';
 $html .='</a></div><div class="tile__details"><div class="tile__title">';
    $html .= ''. $title .'</div></div></div>'; the url is working fine but the title still coming to same place.

Comment: Also when I click the image, having an anchor it should open the linked page but its not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using functions that directly output the image and title rather than appending it to your `$html` variable. You need to switch to functions that return a value instead.

Change the image from:

```
$html .="src='".esc_url(the_post_thumbnail_url()). "'/>";
```

To:

```
$html .= "src='" . esc_url( get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ) . "'/>";
```

And the title from:

```
$html .= the_title();
```

To:

```
$html .= get_the_title();
```

Docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: Thanks Nathan for explaining the reason. Could you please help with the anchor, when I click on it it does not do anything.

Comment: Pleased I could help :) As for the anchor I'm afraid there are too many possibilities to give you any clear direction. Are you doing anything with JavaScript? Errors in console? Have you checked the link is showing correctly in the element inspector? Are you styling it in a way that prevents it from being clicked such as positioning another element over the top of it. The code used to load jQuery in your code needs to go by the way. WordPress provides it for you.

Comment: got it the anchor tag was supposed to cover the entire div tag. Just moved anchor above the pscanvas div. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>
```

Comment: thanks Haring, it worked. could you please see my above comment and help me with the title as well.